# Como posso obter o primeiro elemento de cada elemento pai?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma estrutura assim:

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="iconset"></span> <!-- primeiro elemento -->
    <span class="iconset"></span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <span class="iconset"></span> <!-- primeiro elemento -->
    <span class="iconset"></span>
</div>
```

Preciso selecionar os primeiros elementos de cada bloco. Se eu tento obter desta forma:

```js
$(".container .iconset:first");
```

Eu obtenho somente 1 elemento, mas neste exemplo eu quero obter os 2 elementos.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de se fazer isso com jQuery.

#### Para selecionar ambos os spans do exemplo:

1. Utilizando a pseudoclasse [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) no seletor:

   ```
   var primeiros = $(".container .iconset:first-child");
   ```
2. Utilizando a pseudoclasse [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) no seletor:

   ```
   var primeiros = $(".container .iconset:nth-child(1)");
   ```
3. Utilizando a pseudoclasse [`:first-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/)  (que seleciona o primeiro elemento de determinado tipo, neste caso, spans):

   ```
   var primeiros = $(".container .iconset:first-of-type");
   ```

#### Para selecionar somente o primeiro span do primeiro container:

1. Com o método [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

   ```
   var primeiro = $(".container .iconset").first();
   ```
2. Utilizando a pseudoclasse [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) (extensão do  jQuery, não faz parte do CSS):

   ```
   var primeiro = $(".container .iconset:first");
   ```
3. Com o método [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

   ```
   var primeiro = $(".container .iconset").eq(0);
   ```
4. Com a pseudoclasse [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (extensão do  jQuery, não faz parte do CSS):

   ```
   var primeiro = $(".container .iconset:eq(0)");
   ```

A diferença é que todos os métodos desse segundo grupo primeiro selecionam todos os elementos que atendem ao seletor, e só depois pega o primeiro elemento entre eles.

Answer (score 1):

Existe o seletor [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Você pode utilizar passando o parametro `1` para obter estes elementos. Vejo um [exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cwP6/).

```
var elementos = $(".container .iconset:nth-child(1)");
```